# Counting the vowels in a string using Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have just started learning JavaScript and I am stuck in regular expressions. This program is supposed to count the number of vowels in the entered string and display the vowels.

The program is running fine if the vowels aren't placed together but does not give the right value if the vowels appear together. *e.g.* "tree". the vowels will be shown as "ee" and count will be 1.

```html
Type a word here : <input type="text" id="word1">
<input type="button" value="Vowels" onclick="Vowels()">
```

```js
function Vowels(){
  var String1 = document.getElementById('word1').value;
  var re = new RegExp(/[aeiou]+/gi);
  var Vowels1 = String1.match(re);
  alert(Vowels1);
  if (Vowels1.length>=1)
  {
    alert("The number of vowels are:" + Vowels1.length);
  }
  else
  {
    alert("No vowels in the word"); 
  }
}
```

Kindly help me find the right regular expression, and the `else` statement is not working. Kindly help me fix it.

Comment: Just remove the `+`. So `"tree".match(/[aeiou]/gi).length` gives you `2`

Answer (score 3):

Just lose the `+` -- your expression is picking up groups of consecutive vowels as a single match.

```
var re = /[aeiou]/gi;
```

As for the `else`, this line will fail when there are no matches (and `Vowels1` is `null`):

```
if (Vowels1.length>=1)
```

At that point, the script stops executing, and we never run the `else` block.

So change it to:

```
if (Vowels1 && (Vowels1.length > 0))
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine now. Can you kindly suggest some material to learn javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
function getVowels(str) {
  var m = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
  return m === null ? 0 : m.length;
}
```